# Queue/De-Queue between Java and C++ for Android

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, queue

Is there a well known way of enquing/dequing data between Java and C++ under android? I am trying to show images to the user from various steps I perform in C++ but the problem is that with each step I have to return to Java and then come back to C++.

I thought of this queue usage but I am not sure if it is a good thing to use or even possible to use queues. Both at Java and C++ end. Two queues under separate threads. One thread (C++) inserting into the queue and the other (Java) removing from the queue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on the OpenJDK without using JNI. (In fact I have an implementation for OpenJDK/HotSPot)  But AFAIK, you end up using JNI in some place for in Android as it doesn't use intrincis i.e. the ability to access off heap memory without JNI.

Is the JNI on Android really that expensive?  I would have thought it takes around a micro-second or less.

Comment: Its not the expensiveness that bothers but rather it is the flow of the program. My final output on image manipulation is done and shown in the end. I want to show the intermediate steps. But cant seem to figure out the best approach.

Comment: @Wajih Let me attempt to rephrase. You want to have some processing in C++ but you want to display progress/output in Java?  If this is the case, the simplest approach might be a pipe, named pipe, or socket connection.  On one end you write data and on the other end you read it as a stream.  This stream could be logged to your GUI or displayed as an image etc.

Comment: Hmmm. That is one way of doing it. May be I should go for that. Thanks for the tip!